# Handling legacy url's for any level in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have upgraded an old php site to asp.net MVC and I want to handle all the legacy URL's. I don't need them to map to the current pages as the content is all new but I do want to catch all requests for .php page and send them to the homepage (ideally with a permanent redirect for the search engines).

This works but only at the root level:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
             "LegacySite",                                                    // Route name
             "{OldPage}.php",                           // URL with parameters
             new { controller = "Home", action = "index" },  // Parameter defaults
             new string[] { "EatIn.Website.Controllers" }
        );
```

I want to get all .php pages regardless of the folder they were in.

Comment: William, glad this worked for you - thanks for the 'gong' ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

William,

I've got a similar scenario in an old mvc 1 website. However, the logic may still fit. I had a number of known pages and a variety of unknown pages to deal with. at the time, I dealt with it in the action using a rather cludgy approach as detailed below:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string routeval = (string)this.RouteData.Values["file"];
    var dicT = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    // oh deary me - hardcoded values
    dicT.Add("algarve", 1);
    dicT.Add("brazil", 5);
    dicT.Add("colorado", 4);
    dicT.Add("morocco", 2);
    dicT.Add("thailand", 6);
    // what, no test for culture/case :-)
    if (dicT.ContainsKey(routeval))
    {
        var routeData = new RouteValueDictionary(
            new
            {
                controller = "Property",
                action = "Details",
                id = dicT[routeval],
                Lang = "en"
            });
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "Property", routeData);
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**[edit]** - found another 'useful' bit of info on this from that old mvc1 app. you can add the following to your base controller:

```
public class LegacyUrlRoute : RouteBase
{
    // source: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/108/Handling-Legacy-URLs-with-ASP.NET-MVC
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        const string status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        var request = httpContext.Request;
        var response = httpContext.Response;
        var legacyUrl = request.Url.ToString();
        var newUrl = "";

        if (legacyUrl.Contains("/villas/") || legacyUrl.EndsWith("asp"))
        {
            if (legacyUrl.Contains("/villas/"))
                newUrl = "/en/home/Destinations";
            else if (legacyUrl.EndsWith("asp"))
            {
                newUrl = "/en/home/index";
                if (legacyUrl.Contains("about"))
                    newUrl = "/en/home/AboutUs";
                if (legacyUrl.Contains("offers"))
                    newUrl = "/en/home/Offers";
                if (legacyUrl.Contains("contact"))
                    newUrl = "/en/home/ContactUs";
                if (legacyUrl.Contains("destinations"))
                    newUrl = "/en/home/destinations";
                if (legacyUrl.Contains("faq"))
                    newUrl = "/en/home/Faq";
                if (legacyUrl.Contains("terms"))
                    newUrl = "/en/home/Terms";
                if (legacyUrl.Contains("privacy"))
                    newUrl = "/en/home/Privacy";
            }

            response.Status = status;
            response.RedirectLocation = newUrl;
            response.End();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then put a new route in your global.asax file:

```
routes.Add(new LegacyUrlRoute());
```

basically, i 'knew' that i was looking for a route value that contained a parameter of 'file' along the lines of `www.url.com/somepage.asp?file=algarve` etc.. (this was how the old asp classic site worked and i knew that the present one didn't have this). For the 'known' routes that i wanted to redirect to, i used the logic that did the `RedirectToAction`, everything else just went via the default `Index() View()`.

As i said, cludgy and not neccesarily how i'd do it now (some 2.5 years later) but it was an example that i had 'floating around' and it actually works!! :D

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[RouteMagic](http://routemagic.codeplex.com/)** by Phil Haack - maybe it will help you.

Here's a blog entry that describes route redirection:
http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/02/redirecting-routes-to-maintain-persistent-urls.aspx

Comment: I need the routes to be a permanent redirect and this doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: It does: public static RedirectRoute Redirect(this RouteCollection routes, Func<RouteCollection, RouteBase> routeMapping, bool permanent = false)