# How do you Route a page to an Attribute Route in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm in the process of migrating some of our legacy aspx pages to a shiny new MVC based architecture.  However, during the transition, I still need to support the old routes, and just either redirect, or render the relevant mvc action.

The issue I have is that 1 aspx that used to handle multiple purposes is now multiple MVC actions.

I figured that I could use a custom RouteBase with:

```
        routes.Add("legacy", new LegacyPageOverride());
```

That looks like:

```
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.Headers == null)
            return null;

        if (httpContext.Request.Url == null)
            return null;

        if (httpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.StartsWith("/legacy/login/default.aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return LoginRoute(httpContext.Request);

        return null;
    }

    private RouteData LoginRoute(HttpRequestBase httpRequestBase)
    {
        if (httpRequestBase?.Url == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpRequestBase));

        var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Account");

        if (httpRequestBase.Form["SAMLResponse"] != null || 
            httpRequestBase.QueryString["SAMLResponse"] != null)
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "SAML");
        }
        else if (httpRequestBase.QueryString["logged_out"] != null)
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "logoff");
        }
        else
        {
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "SignIn");
        }
        return routeData;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

I've debugged it through, but although this logic is firing, and GetRouteData is returning a RouteData object, I still receive a 404.

I've tried:

routes.RouteExistingFiles = true (and false).

Deleting the files I'm trying to override the route for.

Trying to remove the staticFile module from the web.config.

I can't use UrlRewriting as I can't get the module installed on all the webservers that host the site.  I also need to route based on POST parameters, and have these re-submitted to the resultant page.

**UPDATE:**

I've narrowed this down to attribute routing.  If I disable that on the specific controller action, everything works fine.

So this doesn't work:
      [Route("login)]
      public ActionResult Login()

This does:
      public ActionResult Login()

Any ideas how to make it work? I read something MS_DirectRouteMatches?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC route to catch all *.aspx requests](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36156496/181087).

Comment: Not really, looks like it's maybe attribute routing throwing off the routeData. ps. love MvcSiteMapProvider

Comment: Oh, of course - 404. Have you seen [Dots in URL causes 404 with ASP.NET mvc and IIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12151501/181087)? Using a `.` in your URL would prevent your request from ever reaching MVC (unless you use `RunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`, which I wouldn't recommend - better to use a variation of the solution in the accepted answer).

Comment: nope, add the handler, but still getting "The resource cannot be found." tried it in a new solution to role out legacy code.  My route is being hit as I can debug, and it returns what I would expect, it just ends with the resource cannot be found message.

Comment: even RAMMFAR doesn't help

Comment: I was able to confirm your findings. One more piece of information - this only seems to happen when the method you are routing to has `Route` attribute applied. On one hand, this seems like it may be a bug. On the other hand, it doesn't make much sense to return the same controller and action route values from 2 different routes (`RouteAttribute` and `LegacyPageOverride` seem to collide). Furthermore, this whole use case feels like you should be doing a 301 redirect instead of routing directly. But AFAIK you need to use a controller for 301. See link in my first comment for ideas.

Comment: The issue is post data to an endpoint that I can't move, and very old browser support.  I thought that simply routing on the backend would allow us to have the old URL, but use an MVC controller/action for it.

Comment: In that case, routing is a better choice than redirecting. I suggest you remove the attribute routes from your 3 action methods and route them using convention-based routes - at least it will function. Or, just remove attribute routing altogether - it is pretty limited compared to convention-based routing. You may also want to [report this issue as a bug to the MVC team](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic).